# Does anyone know what a cmap file has to look like

Tags: pdf, viewers, font-encodings, postscript

This may be an off-topic fringe case, but I need it for `pdftex`...

I made an encoding QS7 for ASCII+Greek and now the only thing missing is a CMAP file to enable copying text from `acroread`.

I made the following file `qs7.cmap` by trying to mimic the other ones in [the cmap package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cmap) but as this has to be proper PostScript (which I know nothing about), there are probably a million things I can have done wrong without even noticing.

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 Resource-CMap
%%DocumentNeededResources: ProcSet (CIDInit)
%%IncludeResource: ProcSet (CIDInit)
%%BeginResource: CMap (TeX-QS7-0)
%%Title: (TeX-QS7-0 TeX QS7 0)
%%Version: 1.000
%%EndComments
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<< /Registry (TeX)
/Ordering (QS7)
/Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /TeX-QS7-0 def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<00> <FF>
endcodespacerange
64 beginbfchar
<00> <0060>
<01> <00B4>
<02> <02C6>
<03> <02DC>
<04> <00A8>
<05> <02DD>
<06> <02DA>
<07> <02C7>
<08> <02D8>
<09> <00AF>
<0A> <02D9>
<0B> <00B8>
<0C> <02DB>
<0D> <201A>
<0E> <2039>
<0F> <203A>
<10> <201C>
<11> <201D>
<12> <201E>
<13> <00AB>
<14> <00BB>
<15> <2013>
<16> <2014>
<17> <200B>
<19> <0131>
<1A> <0237>
<1B> <FB00>
<1C> <FB01>
<1D> <FB02>
<1E> <FB03>
<1F> <FB04>
<20> <2423>
<21> <0021>
<22> <0022>
<23> <0023>
<24> <0024>
<25> <0025>
<26> <0026>
<27> <2019>
<28> <0028>
<29> <0029>
<2A> <002A>
<2B> <002B>
<2C> <002C>
<2D> <002D>
<2E> <002E>
<2F> <002F>
<30> <0030>
<31> <0031>
<32> <0032>
<33> <0033>
<34> <0034>
<35> <0035>
<36> <0036>
<37> <0037>
<38> <0038>
<39> <0039>
<3A> <003A>
<3B> <003B>
<3C> <003C>
<3D> <003D>
<3E> <003E>
<3F> <003F>
<40> <0040>
endbfchar
64 beginbfchar
<41> <0041>
<42> <0042>
<43> <0043>
<44> <0044>
<45> <0045>
<46> <0046>
<47> <0047>
<48> <0048>
<49> <0049>
<4A> <004A>
<4B> <004B>
<4C> <004C>
<4D> <004D>
<4E> <004E>
<4F> <004F>
<50> <0050>
<51> <0051>
<52> <0052>
<53> <0053>
<54> <0054>
<55> <0055>
<56> <0056>
<57> <0057>
<58> <0058>
<59> <0059>
<5A> <005A>
<5B> <005B>
<5C> <005C>
<5D> <005D>
<5E> <005E>
<5F> <005F>
<60> <2018>
<61> <0061>
<62> <0062>
<63> <0063>
<64> <0064>
<65> <0065>
<66> <0066>
<67> <0067>
<68> <0068>
<69> <0069>
<6A> <006A>
<6B> <006B>
<6C> <006C>
<6D> <006D>
<6E> <006E>
<6F> <006F>
<70> <0070>
<71> <0071>
<72> <0072>
<73> <0073>
<74> <0074>
<75> <0075>
<76> <0076>
<77> <0077>
<78> <0078>
<79> <0079>
<7A> <007A>
<7B> <007B>
<7C> <007C>
<7D> <007D>
<7E> <007E>
<7F> <002D>
<80> <00A1>
endbfchar
64 beginbfchar
<81> <00BF>
<82> <20AC>
<83> <20AF>
<84> <00A6>
<85> <00A7>
<86> <037E>
<87> <00A9>
<88> <037A>
<89> <0387>
<8A> <00AC>
<8B> <00AD>
<8C> <2015>
<8D> <00B0>
<8E> <00B1>
<8F> <00B2>
<90> <00B3>
<91> <0384>
<92> <0385>
<93> <0374>
<94> <0375>
<95> <0386>
<96> <00B7>
<97> <0388>
<98> <0389>
<9E> <03AD>
<9F> <038C>
<A0> <03AE>
<A1> <03AF>
<A2> <0390>
<BD> <00BD>
<BE> <038E>
<BF> <038F>
<C0> <038A>
<C1> <0391>
<C2> <0392>
<C3> <0393>
<C4> <0394>
<C5> <0395>
<C6> <0396>
<C7> <0397>
<C8> <0398>
<C9> <0399>
<CA> <039A>
<CB> <039B>
<CC> <039C>
<CD> <039D>
<CE> <039E>
<CF> <039F>
<D0> <03A0>
<D1> <03A1>
<D3> <03A3>
<D4> <03A4>
<D5> <03A5>
<D6> <03A6>
<D7> <03A7>
<D8> <03A8>
<D9> <03A9>
<DA> <03AA>
<DB> <03AB>
<E0> <03B0>
<E1> <03B1>
<E2> <03B2>
<E3> <03B3>
<E4> <03B4>
endbfchar
27 beginbfchar
<E5> <03B5>
<E6> <03B6>
<E7> <03B7>
<E8> <03B8>
<E9> <03B9>
<EA> <03BA>
<EB> <03BB>
<EC> <03BC>
<ED> <03BD>
<EE> <03BE>
<EF> <03BF>
<F0> <03C0>
<F1> <03C1>
<F2> <03C2>
<F3> <03C3>
<F4> <03C4>
<F5> <03C5>
<F6> <03C6>
<F7> <03C7>
<F8> <03C8>
<F9> <03C9>
<FA> <03CA>
<FB> <03CB>
<FC> <03CC>
<FD> <03CD>
<FE> <03CE>
<FF> <03AC>
endbfchar
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end
%%EndResource
%%EOF
```

The only indication I have that it didn't work is that when copying greek text it comes out as rubbish.

The file *is* loaded

```
[3<<t1.cmap>><<t2a.cmap>><<qs7.cmap>>]
```

together with T2A, and copying russian text works like a charm. So I suspect the problem lies in the file.

Is there any way of debugging this? Can I get a spelled-out error message?

Is there anything (apart from putting the file in the right place) I need to configure?

Obviously, I'm using [the cmap package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cmap) for this.

If there is any other .SX site where this would be more appropriate, please advise.

Comment: @egreg did you infer this from the numbers in front? Some characters are missing, for instance `<18>` which is "perthousandzero" and doesn't seem to have a unicode point. Same with `t1.cmap`. I counted again, it's 64.

Comment: @LevBishop Wow, now this is embarassing. I didn't know this at all. That's the solution, obviously. If you turn this comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than using the `cmap` package, you could use the pdftex built in functionality:

```
\input glyphtounicode.tex 
\input glyphtounicode-cmr.tex 
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

This doesn't rely on the tex encoding so it should work.